# Simple expression is reportedly recursive in parser combinators

Tags: scala, recursion, overloading, overriding, parser-combinators

Guess what is the result of this compilation?

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    lazy val literal = int  
    lazy val int = rep("0")
}
```

Compiler says that [`int` is recursive and asks for the type of it](http://scastie.org/13947). My experiment says that the core of the recursion is hidden in the declaration of the literal! Remove it and you will see that recursion is gone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is relevant here that `JavaTokenParsers` defines something called `literal`.

And `rep("0")` is actually `rep(literal("0"))` (`literal` is an implicit conversion from `String` to `Parser[String]`).

But the `literal` in `JavaTokenParsers` takes an argument, and yours doesn't. So you might expect that yours would simply overload, and not override, and there would be no conflict — and no mutual recursion between `int` and `literal`.

And in fact, if you supply explicit types:

```
object ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  lazy val literal: Parser[List[String]] = int 
  lazy val int: Parser[List[String]] = rep("0")
}
```

This flies by the compiler just fine.

So why is the explicit-return-type rule for recursion being triggered when the return types are omitted?

This is a rather subtle question, I think. I'm not confident I know exactly what's going on here. I cannot find specific language in the Scala Language Specification that covers it.

My best guess is that at the time the explicit-return-type rule is triggered, the compiler is still at a relatively early phase where it hasn't yet resolved exactly what or isn't an overload or an override. Not having the return types yet, it has to proceed based on partial information about the types involved.

But it does know that your definition of `literal` involves the name `int`, and your definition of `int` involves the name `literal`, and so it considers that recursive and gives up.

Comment: Javadoc says only about the `def literal(String)` defined in `JavaTokenParsers`. This is also the method you are referring to to explain the circular dependency. You insensibly replace `def (arg)` with `lazy val overriding` to justify the reasonable behaviour of the parser. Am I missing something?

I am doing it to match the LRM specification. I am doing a runnable specification. It is hard to tell if my desire to name it literalliteral is intentional or unintentional.

Comment: Even if compiler converts `val something` into a def behind the scenes, it should distinguish between the call to `literal` and call to `literal(with argument)`. How can you call it `right` after it is unable to distinguish between the overloaded functions?

Comment: You may think the compiler "should distinguish", but the compiler can't read your mind.

Comment: You are saying that the number of arguments is only available to my mind. That is why Scala compiler does not support the overloaded functions. This is news to me.

Comment: I have revised my answer. The situation here is more subtle than I initially realized.